# To copy file with file name "abc.txt" to destination

Tags: powershell

I have a scanario where I need to copy file called "abc.txt" from its locations which is not known to destination location "C:\Temp".

We need to search "abc.txt" file and then copy the file to "C:\Temp"

Here source location is unknown and only the file name is known which is to be copied. Can we make use of current directory for this? If yes how can we ?

Comment: The specification makes no sense. What's the [real scenario](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understand  the requirements correctly, you need to find a file in the current folder with the name "abc.txt" and, if the file exist

```
$AllFiles = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Name "abc.txt"

foreach ($File in $AllFiles)
{   
Write-Host $File
    Copy-Item -Path $File -Destination "C:\Temp\"
}
```

If you want to look for the file in the current Folder AND the subfolders, use the "-Recurse" parameter, see Documentation of Get-Childitem:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7